# I have a list of words related to a particular word. How to select 3-4 most associated words from the list using python?

Tags: python, text-mining

For example :
*Search keyword:   Food*

**For this word, I have a list:**

`substance
life
growth
stimulus food
thought
Substance
Food chain
Series
dependent
Foodie
Colloq
Person
cult
food gourmet
Food poisoning
Illness
Food processor
Machine
Foodstuff
Substance
Food value
Nourishing power`

From this list, I want to select 3-4 words:

```
1. life

2.growth

3.food poisoning

4.food chain
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, can you edit your question and add more details?

Comment: Is the list with the associated words sorted on their relevance to the search keyword or are you asking how to find a relevant association score? If the list is sorted (i.e. you have a python list with the associated words) you could just take the first 4 with `associatedWordList[:4]`, but you probably would want to remove the duplicates first.

Comment: @EmilH Sorry, no they are not sorted according to their relevance. That is what I want to do

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ I want to find the 3-4 most associated words from the list of related words